# Custom position tooltip on top

Tags: javascript, import, charts, chart.js, tooltip

I am trying to make this example work: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.5.1/samples/tooltip/position.html

because it have an option to position the tooltip on the bottom of the graph. I need to do so because I have way too much data in my graph and when I move my cursor the tooltip wiggle around too much. My biggest problem is that, even after adding type="module" to my script tag I still get the following error when I do import {Tooltip} from '/chart.js/dist/chart.js':

Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/chart.js/dist/chart.js' does not provide an export named 'Tooltip'

And that is even after losing 3 hours trying to search on every corner of google.
Thanks you so much to anyone who can help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using a script tag the `Chart` object is made available to you.

So you can just write:

```js
Chart.Tooltip.positioners.customName = customPositionerFunction
```

There is no need to import anything

Comment: Oh my god! This worked! Why the doc did not say how to do it like that? Did I miss it? How did you know this? Anyway thank you SO much!

Comment: [`New modes can be defined by adding functions to the Chart.Tooltip.positioners map.`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.7.1/configuration/tooltip.html#custom-position-modes)